# How to load a saved Tensorflow model and evaluate it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

This is how I saved the model.

```py
# First created serving_input func
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns))

# Save Estimator as a tf model
classifier.export_saved_model("location", serving_input_fn)
```

This produced a folder which has "saved_model.pb" file and a folder "variable"

The issue is I tried to load and run the model by

```py
imported_model = tf.saved_model.load("/folderLocation")

imported_model_res = imported_model.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(x_test, y_test, training=False))
```

But I get an error which says

> AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You first need to convert the model to keras.

Try the following:

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(path)

class LayerFromSavedModel(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LayerFromSavedModel, self).__init__()
        self.vars = loaded.variables
    def call(self, inputs):
        return loaded.signatures['serving_default'](inputs)

input = tf.keras.Input(...)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, LayerFromSavedModel()(input))
model.save('saved_model')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answe, could you clarify what goes in tf.eras.Input(....)
Thanks

Comment: The code I posted was taken from the following [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42425). Consider reading it to understand what this code does.